# display data from 2 tables in excel from sql server

Tags: excel, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2, excel-2010

I want to display 2 table data from SQL Server to Excel file. Each table has 2 columns.

I know that we can do this using Data tab. But what I could understand is we need to create 2 connections for the 2 tables.

**Can we use a single connection and using this connection display the data from 2 tables?**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Nope, you cannot connect two tables with one connection.

There is workaround to join tables in SQL query or use Union and index each table with column with name of the table.

Or if you do not want to use queries, try Microsoft Query from Excel, here is link to see how to use it.

https://help.acctivate.com/articles/3727/

Still I would suggest to do two connections.

Comment: Thanks Peter, let me check it.

Comment: The link is joining the 2 tables. I want to show the separate data from 2 tables and not the joined data.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Nope for me. Only way to do this is to do Join, if there is any common id or to do Union in your query (but you will have to ensure to have equal number of columns) or to do two separate connections. You can save the first connection and load it again to make it faster.